# References display in spbasic style

Tags: bibtex, sv-classes

I am using spbasic for typesetting a Springer Journal paper. References as listed inconsistently when they are listed. *dot and space* are missing after the author year format when author names have **et al.** in it. Following figure shows the inconsistency.

[image]

I am using

```
\documentclass[referee]{svjour3}
```

My question is how to get **dot and space** after the starting author et al. (year) citation style

Comment: Off-topic: Please add the instruction `\hyphenation{double-stein}` to your preamble. This will prevent the horrendous-looking 'Dou-blestein' outcome from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the header of the file `spbasic.bst`:

```
%% For use with the natbib package (see below). Default is author-year citations. %%
%%   When citations are numbered, please use \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}.        %%
```

In short, one *must* load the `natbib` citation management package if one wishes to employ the `spbasic` bibliography style correctly.

If you wish to generate numeric-style citation call-outs, be sure to load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a full-fledged minimum working example, which employs the `natbib` package. Note that the citation call-outs are *not* repeated at the start of each formatted bib entry. I've highlighted the citation call-outs as well as the formatted name blocks in the bib entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass[referee]{svjour3}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
% see https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1282040.1282058 and
%     https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1018435.1021693
@inproceedings{avw:2007, 
author = {Adamo-Villani, Nicoletta and Wright, Kelly},
title = {{SMILE}: An Immersive Learning Game for Deaf and Hearing Children},
year = {2007},
isbn = {9781450318303},
publisher = {Association for Computing Machinery},
address = {New York, NY, USA},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1145/1282040.1282058},
doi = {10.1145/1282040.1282058},
booktitle = {ACM SIGGRAPH 2007 Educators Program},
pages = {17–es},
keywords = {virtual reality, 3D animation, virtual learning environments, sign language education},
location = {San Diego, California},
series = {SIGGRAPH '07}
}
@inproceedings{avdm:2004,
author = {Adamo-Villani, Nicoletta and Doublestein, John and Martin, Zachary},
title  = {The {MathSigner}: An Interactive Learning Tool for {American Sign Language} {K-3} Mathematics},
year   = {2004},
isbn   = {0769521770},
publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
address = {USA},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the Information Visualisation, Eighth International Conference},
pages   = {713–716},
numpages = {4},
series  = {IV~'04}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\usepackage{microtype} % optional
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\hyphenation{double-stein}

\begin{document}
\cite{avw:2007}, \cite{avdm:2004}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My question is how to get dot and space after the starting author et al. (year) citation style

Comment: @tex - There seems to be some unfortunate confusion between (a) the format of the citation call-outs (e.g., `author et al. (year)`) in the body of the document and (b) the format of the typeset bibliographic entries. I know of no BibTeX bibliography style that would deliberately clog up the bibliography section by prefixing/repeating the citation call-out to the formatted entry.

Comment: @tex - I've posted an addendum in which I highlight the difference between the citation call-outs and the formatted bibliographic entries.